# How to write in HDF5 file using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytables

So in my code I have something like this:

```
import tables
import bson

def proc():
    data = bson.decode_file_iter(open('file.bson'), 'rb'))
    atom = tables.Float64Atom()
    f = tables.open_file('t.hdf5', mode='w')
    array_c = f.create_earray(f.root, 'data', atom, (0, m))

    for c,d in enumerate(data):
        for e,p in enumerate(d['id']):
            x = some_array1bym()
            array_c.append(x)

     f.close()
```

This works fine, but I want to right this with multiprocessing, since I am new to this, I dont know how to do this exactly, I found something like this:

```
def proc():
    NCORE = 6               
    data = bson.decode_file_iter(open('file.bson'), 'rb'))
    atom = tables.Float64Atom()
    f = tables.open_file('t.hdf5', mode='w')
    array_c = f.create_earray(f.root, 'data', atom, (0, m))

    def process(q, iolock):
        while True:
           d = q.get()
           if d is None:
               break
           for e, p in enumerate(d['id']):
               x = some_array1bym()
               array_c.append(x)

     q = mp.Queue(maxsize=NCORE)
     iolock = mp.Lock()
     pool = mp.Pool(NCORE, initializer=process, initarg=(q,iolock))

     for c,d in enumerate(data):
        q.put(d)

     for _ in range(NCORE):
         q.put(None)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()

     f.close()
```

This however gives me an empty file.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Citing Wes McKinney from the book "Python for Data Analysis":
*HDF5 is not a database. It is best suited for write-once, read-many datasets. While data can be added to file at any time, if multiple writers do so simultaneously, the file can become corrupted.*

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what goes wrong as your example cannot be executed. Perhaps you could replace `data` and `some_array1bym` with suitable placeholders to allow other users to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood the use of `multiprocessing.Pool` slightly. When you initialize a `Pool` it starts up `N` worker processes. The `initializer` argument is just a function that is run once on each worker process when it starts up. It's not a task that the processes will be performing later. You then use methods like `Pool.map` or `Pool.apply` (or their async complements) to actually submit jobs to the pool for processing.

Comment: In OP's example, the `initializer` function does all the work (it takes tasks from a queue until it sees a `None`) so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Not so. The queue is empty when it's called so it returns immediately.

Comment: If the queue is empty, the the call to `q.get()` will block until there is an item to get. The `initializer` method doesn't return until the `if d is None: break` condition is satisfied.

Comment: Oh that may be, but that would still then be a related problem to misuse of Pool.

Comment: I think the problem may have to do with the `array_c` variable. After the `Pool` forks, each worker will get a copy of this variable. I'm not too familiar with `pytables` so I'm not sure if a) every one of these copies will try to write to the hdf5 file, giving undefined results or b) only the copy in the main thread, which is empty, will write to the file when `f.close()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may have to do with the `array_c` variable. After the Pool forks, each worker will get a **copy** of this variable. This will results in either a) every one of these copies of `array_c` will try to write to the hdf5 file, giving undefined results or b) only the copy in the main process, which is empty, will write to the file when `f.close()` is called. I'm not sure which as I am not familiar with the internals of `pytables`.

In contrast to `array_c`, `q` and `iolock` are shared between all workers and the main thread. `q` is an `mp.Queue` instance and `iolock` is an `mp.Lock` instance, and these classes are specially designed to be used by multiple processes at once. I don't think the same is true of `pytables` classes.

You should be using the `mp.Lock` instance to ensure that only one process writes to the file at once. I think what you will have to do is modify your `process` function to something like the following:

```
def process(q, iolock):
    while True:
        d = q.get()
        if d is None:
            break
        for e, p in enumerate(d['id']):
            x = some_array1bym()
            # acquire lock to ensure only one process writes data at once
            iolock.acquire()
            # get new handle to hdf5 file in append mode
            f = tables.open_file('t.hdf5', mode='a')
            # get new handle to data set and append new data
            array_c = tables.EArray(f.root, 'data')
            array_c.append(x)
            # close file and release lock to allow another process to write
            f.close()
            iolock.release()
```